# PHP Return results via MySQL Based on timeStamp and the Current time

Tags: php

I'm writing a little bit of PHP, but Im a serious nOOb.

I want to compare the current time (The time now) with a timestamp in a table, stored like 1085225495.

If the timestamp is under 1 hour old, then do:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET visible=0;
```

Otherwise ignore.

Any ideas in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
update your_table
set visible = 0
where your_timestamp_field >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(subdate(now(), interval 1 hour))
```

As explanation, here's a select that might help you :

```
mysql> select now(), subdate(now(), interval 1 hour), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(subdate(now(), interval 1 hour))\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                                          now(): 2009-09-17 18:58:31
                subdate(now(), interval 1 hour): 2009-09-17 17:58:31
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(subdate(now(), interval 1 hour)): 1253203111
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here :

- *now()* gets the current date and time
- the `subdate()` gives 1 hour before now
- and `unix_timestamp()` converts that to a unix timestamp

You might also do a substraction of 3600 seconds on `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())`, instead of using subdate... But I like the subdate call : I find it easier to immediatly understand that you want 1 hour *(and not a magic number like 3600)*

Comment: You can use that query with `mysql_query` (or the mysqli or PDO equivalents), like you are doing now -- the only thing is that you don't need to do any calculation on the PHP side : everything is done by that one query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it entirely in MySQL

```
UPDATE foo SET visible=0 
WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp))<3600;
```

UNIX_TIMESTAMP() gives you the number of seconds since the epoch, and subtracting the timestamp seconds from the current seconds gives you the age in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE SET visible = 0 WHERE myTimestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME()) - 3600
```

Comment: $myQueryUpdate = "UPDATE mdl_course SET visible=0 WHERE myTimestamp >= CURTIME() - 3600 AND metacourse=0";


Why doesnt this work?